# How to select between different child components, depending on code higher up?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

Below is a component for a `List`/`<ul>` where there is a `<li>` for each item in `classesByName`. Is there any way to decide between using the component `<ClassItemAnchor />` and an alternative, say `<ClassItemButton />` depending on code higher up (outside of `<ClassList />`)? Otherwise, I'd have to create a new `<ul>` component to have a different `<li>` component?

```
import ClassItemAnchor from "./ClassItemAnchor"

const ClassList = ({ classesByName, getChat, searchName }) => {

    return (
        <ul className="chat-list">
            {classesByName.map((Class) => (
                <ClassItemAnchor
                    key={Class.id}
                    Class={Class}
                    searchName={searchName}
                    getChat={getChat}
                />
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}

export default ClassList
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a prop named `isAnchor` (Boolean) from parent to conditionally render the `ClassItemAnchor` and `ClassItemButton`.

```
const ClassList = ({ classesByName, getChat, searchName, isAnchor = true }) => {
  return (
    <ul className="chat-list">
      {classesByName.map((Class) =>
        isAnchor ? (
          <ClassItemAnchor
            key={Class.id}
            Class={Class}
            searchName={searchName}
            getChat={getChat}
          />
        ) : (
          <ClassItemButton
            key={Class.id}
            Class={Class}
            searchName={searchName}
            getChat={getChat}
          />
        )
      )}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

if `isAnchor` is true , it will render `ClassItemAnchor` else `ClassItemButton`

**Usage**

```
<ClassList isAnchor={true}/>
```